# Is there a way to make Resharper create a non-existing Razor view using my custom template?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, resharper

While developing ASP.NET MVC, when an Action does not have a corresponding View, Resharper will show options:

- Create Razor View `Edit` with layout
- Create Razor View `Edit`
- (other options)

What I want is to add my own Resharper file template as an option here, like this:

- Create Razor View from "Search Form" template
- Create Razor View from "Edit Form" template

Is there a way to get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but it looks like you can write a plugin to do this for you. I'd suggest getting the ReSharper SDK, then opening the assemblies in the %PROGRAMFILES%\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.1\bin folder in a decompiler (dotPeek, natch).

Take a look at IMvcQuickFixTemplateProvider, and the MvcQuickFixTemplateProviderBase in JetBrains.ReSharper.Intentions.Razor.QuickFixes.Mvc.

The MVC quick fix that is invoked to prompt you to create a new view loops over all providers registered with the system and adds three items - partial view, view with layout and simple view. You could create a class that implements IMvcQuickFixTemplateProvider for each template you're interested in. You would then need to create 3 templates, for partial, with layout and just view. This requires knowing all templates at compile time, though.

If you don't know all the templates before hand, you could try creating a class that implements IQuickFix, and takes AspConfigurableNotResolvedErrorHighlighting as a constructor parameter. This will add your quick fix to the error highlighting for an unresolved view, and you can now do whatever you want, displaying any actions in the menu for any templates you've got. Take a look at MvcViewQuickFix for details on how ReSharper does it.

Comment: I didn't have the time to completely check your solution yet but it seems promising. I'm gonna accept your solution and I'll give you feedback when I get it done. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've found the classes you mentioned. Once I implement my own MvcQuickFixTemplateProviderBase, how do I replace the existing one?

Comment: Or add my own menu items based on the existing ones?

Comment: You wouldn't replace the existing one. You'd just add to them. So you'd get a list of your options, plus the original ones. You'd add your options in exactly the same way the existing code does - override GetTemplateGuid and return the guid of a live template (save to disk and look at the xml file, you'll see the identifier)